# Функция которая принимает два аргумента , и возвращает длину и номер строки

Tags: javascript

**Task:** Написать функцию, которая принимает строку в качестве аргумента и возвращает длину строки, а второй параметр  — символ, который будет искать в строке

*For example:*

```
console.log(countChar("Some word", "w"));
```

*// 9, 6;*

длину вернуть-то легко, ну как  со вторым параметром будет взаимодействовать

Тут без двух функций не обойтись?

Comment: Чувствителен ли поиск к региструрегистр (большие и маленькие), и что должно быть, если нет такой буквы в строке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка имеет свойство `.length`, которое хранит длину строки.
Индексы в JavaScript начинаются с `0`, поэтому результат будет 9,5.
Если нужно вывести именно `6`, то нужно сделать проверку на то, что `indexOf()` находит букву в вашем массиве и добавить к ней +1.

```js
const someFunction = function(str, letter) {
  return [str.length, str.indexOf('w')].join(',');
}
console.log(someFunction('Some word', 'w'));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Тут ещё много интересного](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```js
console.log('Some word'.indexOf('w'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```js
const findLenghtAndPosition = (str, char) =>{
    const strLength = str.length;
    const position =  str.indexOf(char) != -1 ? str.indexOf(char) : 0;
    return {
        length: strLength,
        position: position
    }
}

console.log('Find: ', findLenghtAndPosition('hello word', 'w')); //{length: 10, position: 6}
```